# How to get PyTorch 2.0 on Amazon EC2 G5g instances to detect CUDA

Tags: amazon-ec2, pytorch, gpu, aws-graviton

I have been trying to use a G5g EC2 instance with PyTorch 2.0 but I have been struggling to get it working. I want this specific instance because the arm processor makes it significantly cheaper, and this is the only arm instance with a GPU. Amazon had been bragging about PyTorch 2.0 optimization on Graviton (see [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/optimized-pytorch-2-0-inference-with-aws-graviton-processors/)) so I had figured there would be an AMI that came preinstalled with all of this done, however after talking to AWS support that is not the case.

I have tried using AMIs that come with CUDA 11.4 and PyTorch 1.1, and then upgrading both of them, however no matter what I do PyTorch will not install as the CUDA version. I have followed the commands on PyTorch's website to install that specific version, pointing to the CUDA 11.8 wheel after having CUDA 11.8 installed:

```
pip3 install torch --force-reinstall --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cu118
```

but still PyTorch installs as the CPU version. I can confirm this when I run

```
>>import torch
>>torch.cuda.is_available()
False
```

I verified that the CUDA version was 11.8 by running `nvidia-smi`.
I have also tried starting from a blank slate AMI and installing CUDA, then PyTorch, but this led to the same result. The only success I was able to have was on an instance with x86 architecture, but that is not enough for me.

Comment: ngc pytorch containers have an arm variant: https://catalog.ngc.nvidia.com/orgs/nvidia/containers/pytorch/tags

Comment: @reed53 Did you give it try what i suggested?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying one of the pre-built Deep Learning AMIs for AWS Graviton2 specifically G5g family, they will lead you nowhere. Trust me I have been there myself, just like you I was also adamant about making it work with Graviton2, for me it was extra cost, and their availability in Spot Market, You must have got your reasons as well.

Setting up one by yourself is not a difficult task if you know what exactly will work, I have figured it out the hard way and wrote a detailed guide about the exact same issue and we are running that in production.
I installed the latest Nvidia drivers, Cuda 12.2 and CUDNN and Pytorch 2. Following is the snippet from the script to install the GPU driver and toolkit

```bash
setup_gpu() {
    echo "Setting up GPU..."
    wget https://us.download.nvidia.com/tesla/535.104.05/NVIDIA-Linux-aarch64-535.104.05.run
    sh NVIDIA-Linux-aarch64-535.104.05.run --disable-nouveau --silent
    wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/12.2.2/local_installers/cuda_12.2.2_535.104.05_linux_sbsa.run
    sh cuda_12.2.2_535.104.05_linux_sbsa.run --silent --override --toolkit --samples --toolkitpath=/usr/local/cuda-12.2 --samplespath=$CUDA_HOME --no-opengl-libs
    wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cudnn/redist/cudnn/linux-sbsa/cudnn-linux-sbsa-8.9.4.25_cuda12-archive.tar.xz
    tar -xf cudnn-linux-sbsa-8.9.4.25_cuda12-archive.tar.xz
    cp -P cudnn-linux-sbsa-8.9.4.25_cuda12-archive/include/* $CUDA_HOME/include/
    cp -P cudnn-linux-sbsa-8.9.4.25_cuda12-archive/lib/* $CUDA_HOME/lib64/
    chmod a+r $CUDA_HOME/lib64/*
    ldconfig
    rm -fr cu* NVIDIA*
}
```

For PyTorch, you can use the following

```bash
# Install PyTorch from source
install_pytorch() {
    echo "Installing PyTorch..."
    wget https://github.com/ccache/ccache/releases/download/v4.8.3/ccache-4.8.3.tar.xz
    tar -xf ccache-4.8.3.tar.xz
    pushd ccache-4.8.3
    cmake .
    make -j $CPUS
    popd
    dnf install -y numpy
    $USER_EXEC pip3 install typing-extensions
    git clone --recursive https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch.git
    pushd pytorch
    python3 setup.py install
    popd
    ldconfig
    $USER_EXEC pip3 install sympy filelock fsspec networkx
}
```

These snippets need some pre-requisite to install, as well as some custom environment variables, hence you should follow the complete guide about [How to create a custom deep learning AMI](https://mirzabilal.com/deep-learning-with-aws-graviton2-nvidia-tensor-t4g-for-as-low-as-free-with-cuda-12-2-56d8457a6f6d).

The Guide not only explains each step in detail but I have also created a single comprehensive script to do all the dirty work for you.

Setting up one yourself instead of a DLAMI from the marketplace will save you time, instance/block storage, and hence reduce setup (spawn) time. Above all it gives you control over what you need for your environment, i have discussed these issue in detail at [Why your deep-learning AMI is holding you back](https://mirzabilal.com/why-your-aws-deep-learning-ami-is-holding-you-back-and-how-to-fix). Do check it out as I am sure you must have encountered some of the issues if not all while working with DLAMIs.

Disclaimer: I am the author of both of these articles, and i wrote them to share my experience and help others to avoid troubles I had to go through.

Comment: Hi, I tried following this guide however the line
`sh NVIDIA-Linux-aarch64-535.104.05.run --disable-nouveau --silent`
seems to always fail with the following error:

`ERROR: Unable to load the kernel module 'nvidia.ko'. This happens most frequently when this kernel module was built against the wrong or improperly configured kernel sources, with a version of gcc that differs
    from the one used to build the target kernel, or if another driver, such as nouveau, is present and ...`
Have you seen this before?

Comment: @reed53 Did you update your linux before this or not?

Comment: My Linux version appears to be fully updated. I am always launching instances with the latest version of Amazon Linux 2023 AMI and I am also running “sudo dnf update” to check for linux updates, the output is stating that there is nothing to do and that all of my packages / versions are fully up-to-date. I additionally tried changing the version of NVIDIA driver to be the newest one (https://us.download.nvidia.com/tesla/535.129.03/NVIDIA-Linux-aarch64-535.129.03.run) and that seems to give me the same terminal output as the error before.

Comment: @reed53 Let me try it on my end again with latest OS and Nvidia driver, will keep you posted

Comment: @reed53 I have updated the gist and fixed the AMI ID and tested it You can give it a try now https://gist.github.com/bilalmughal/0500f27454a508bd3552fcf03e3adadb

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much, this has been a massive pain

Comment: Happy to help, @reed53. I have been through all this myself so i can relate to it. 